# Need a Regular expression for text match in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, qregexp

Hello i need a regular expression per my sql query to match to text

```
"SIP/(10 NUMBERS)"
```

equals

```
"SIP/1234567890"
```

"SIP" are text
and 10 number randoms 0-9

**UPDATE**

Final text are SIP/0123456789-000001cc

where

```
"SIP/" is text

"0123456789" Always 10 digits 

"-" is character 

"000001cc" is random alphanumeric
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-
```

**Examples:**

```
mysql> select 'SIP/0123456789-000001cc' regexp '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-';
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 'SIP/0123456789-000001cc' regexp '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-' |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'SIP/123456789-000001cc' regexp '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-';
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 'SIP/123456789-000001cc' regexp '^SIP/[[:digit:]]{10}-' |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        0 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hello thanks for reply its work, please i updated my question per news directives can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` to escape `/`

The following RegEx targets SIP followed by `/`and then 10 digit characters:

```
SIP\/\d{10}
```